# Regex to find in between two strings

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="https://domain.com/image.jpg?key=MTI3MzU1NTA2MzQyMDg5NzAxNw%3D%3D.2" />
```

I want to scrape the "content" only.

```
string text = "<meta property=\"og: image\" content=\"https://domain.com/image.jpg?key=MTI3MzU1NTA2MzQyMDg5NzAxNw%3D%3D.2\" />";
```

And then, I do regex like this:

```
string result = Regex.Match(text, "og:image\" content=\"(.*)\" \\/>").Groups[1].Value;
```

The output is empty ("").

Comment: You missed a space in the pattern after `og:`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Now I feel dumb. I overlooked the issue :( Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why two slashes at end?  `//`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary You mean \\ ? If so, to escape / in regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better, cleaner and much more maintainable than Regex

```
var xml = XElement.Parse(text);
var content = xml.Attributes("content").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have only one 'content' in the input you can write your regex as below:

```
string result = Regex.Match(text, ".* content=\"(.*)\".*").Groups[1].Value;
```